# Apollo GraphQL updateQuery to typePolicy

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo, typepolicies

I am beating my head against a wall. I have updated to Apollo 3, and cannot figure out how to migrate an `updateQuery` to a `typePolicy`. I am doing basic continuation based pagination, and this is how I used to merged the results of `fetchMore`:

```
await fetchMore({
  query: MessagesByThreadIDQuery,
  variables: {
    threadId: threadId,
    limit: Configuration.MessagePageSize,
    continuation: token
  },
  updateQuery: (prev, curr) => {
    // Extract our updated message page.
    const last = prev.messagesByThreadId.messages ?? []
    const next = curr.fetchMoreResult?.messagesByThreadId.messages ?? []

    return {
      messagesByThreadId: {
        __typename: 'MessagesContinuation',
        messages: [...last, ...next],
        continuation: curr.fetchMoreResult?.messagesByThreadId.continuation
      }
    }
  }
```

I have made an attempt to write the `merge` `typePolicy` myself, but it just continually loads and throws errors about duplicate identifiers in the Apollo cache. Here is what my `typePolicy` looks like for my query.

```
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        messagesByThreadId: {
          keyArgs: false,
          merge: (existing, incoming, args): IMessagesContinuation => {
            const typedExisting: IMessagesContinuation | undefined = existing
            const typedIncoming: IMessagesContinuation | undefined = incoming
            const existingMessages = (typedExisting?.messages ?? [])
            const incomingMessages = (typedIncoming?.messages ?? [])

            const result = existing ? {
              __typename: 'MessageContinuation',
              messages: [...existingMessages, ...incomingMessages],
              continuation: typedIncoming?.continuation
            } : incoming


            return result
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve my use-case. It seems way harder than it really needs to be. I essentially have to attempt to locate existing items matching the incoming and overwrite them, as well as add any new items that don't yet exist in the cache.

I also have to only apply this logic if a continuation token was provided, because if it's null or undefined, I should just use the incoming value because that indicates that we are doing an initial load.

My document is shaped like this:

```json
{
  "items": [{ id: string, ...others }],
  "continuation": "some_token_value"
}
```

I created a generic type policy that I can use for all my documents that have a similar shape. It allows me to specify the name of the items property, what the key args are that I want to cache on, and the name of the graphql type.

```js
export function ContinuationPolicy(keyArgs: Array<string>, itemPropertyKey: string, typeName: string) {
  return {
    keyArgs,
    merge(existing: any, incoming: any, args: any) {
      if (!!existing && !!args.args?.continuation) {
        const existingItems = (existing ? existing[itemPropertyKey] : [])
        const incomingItems = (incoming ? incoming[itemPropertyKey] : [])
        let items: Array<any> = [...existingItems]

        for (let i = 0; i < incomingItems.length; i++) {
          const current = incomingItems[i] as any
          const found = items.findIndex(m => m.__ref === current.__ref)

          if (found > -1) {
            items[found] === current
          } else {
            items = [...items, current]
          }
        }

        // This new data is a continuation of the last data.
        return {
          __typename: typeName,
          [itemPropertyKey]: items,
          continuation: incoming.continuation
        }
      } else {
        // When we have no existing data in the cache, we'll just use the incoming data.
        return incoming
      }
    }
  }
}
```